# Profile images save as blob vs in filesystem

Tags: android, asp.net, database, azure, filesystems

So I've got a unique system going on which is spread across 2 apps and 1 website. All 3 components of the system will share the same data source now each user has 1 and only 1 image to upload which will be their profile image. I'm debating if I should store them in the file system or the database the trade here are equal in my eyes. Storing them in the file system I'll have to retrieve them in 3 different systems from one server hassle.. on the other hand storing them in the DB could potentially make the DB slow.

One thing I see happening here is what if I make an images table and not back it up and just have all images reference an image in the images table. Worst thing that can happen is I'll lose all images.. xD which isn't really significant

I'm using windows azure to host my database
my website will run asp.net on windows azure and I'm using azure mobile services to serve apps

Answer (score 1):

Since the same image is used by 3 applications, I would recommend using a central place for storing the image instead of storing it locally in the application. The advantage you will get is that if a user updates the image from any application, changes will be reflected in other applications as well without worrying about the synchronization hassles.

However instead of using a database table for storing images, use Windows Azure Blob Storage. It is meant for that purpose only. Furthermore your data is replicated 3 times within same data center and optionally you could geo-replicate the data for additional redundancy. With blob storage you don't have to worry about backups as well.